# How to write Regex to find stock and Price

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

```
var rawItemInfo={"stock":"In Stock","shipping":"<em>Free Shipping</em>","finalPrice":"56.99","itemInfo":"<div class=\"grpPricing\"><div class=\"wrapper\"><div class=\"current\" id=\"singleFinalPrice\"><span class=\"label\">Now:  </span><span>$</span>56<sup>.99</sup></div></div><div
```

I want to extract two information from above string

1: Stock Status "In Stock" which will come always after "Stock":

2 Price $56.99 which is there
some before....`<span>$</span>56<sup>.99</sup>` some code after....

Please help me out to write regex for these two information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract these value using this code

```
var regPattern = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";
Regex regex = new Regex(regPattern);
var data = regex.Match(contact.Name);
data.Groups[1].Value ///"In stock. Limit 1 per customer."
data.Groups[2].Value ///"549.99"
```

Comment: Its fine but only problem with your code is that it is not extracting $ sign too its extracting only 549.99. I need $549.99

Comment: try this one  stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\".*?</span><span>(.?)</span>    Groups[3].value // $